# SQL JPA не видит таблицу, хотя из консоли запрос работает

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

Ошибка: Can't resolve symbol 'client'

[image]

Не понимаю, что ему нужно? Даже если ввести полный путь, ошибка сохраняется(

Comment: А чё за ошибка-то? или мы должны угадать?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Ошибка Can't resolve symbol 'client'

Comment: JPA маппится на сущности @Table

Comment: У меня есть такие Entity с аннотациями Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя аннотацию @Query вы можете явно указать запросы на одном из 2-х языков:

- HQL пример:

  ```
  @Query(value = "from DraftQueueAddress where id = :id")
  List<DraftQueueAddress> findByDraftId(Long id);
  ``|
  ```
- SQL пример:

  ```
  @Query(value = "select * from doc.doc_draft_queue where doc_draft_queue.doc_queue_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
  List<DraftQueueAddress> findByDraftId(Long id);
  ```

Когда вы используете HQL, то не указываете явно название таблицы, а указываете вашу сущность (в моем случае DraftQueueAddress),
с параметром "nativeQuery = true" вы указываете запрос на нужном вам диалекте

[Примеры запросов по HQL](https://javastudy.ru/hibernate/hibernate-hql-examples/)

В случае если вы пишете нативный запрос, то для того чтобы IDEA не подсвечивала красным ей необходимо понять на каком диалекте вы пишете. Комбинацией Alt + Enter на подсвеченной строке появится окно с красной лампочкой и текстом "Assign DataSource", необходимо будет выбрать ваш вариант (например PostgreSQL). После этого проверка синтаксиса будет осуществляться на основе выбранного вами диалекта